# Generic Method Implementing Two Traits

Tags: scala

I'm trying to define a method - it accepts an `A`, which must be a sub-type of 2 traits.

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar
defined trait Bar

scala> def f[A <: Foo, Bar](x: A) = x
f: [A <: Foo, Bar](x: A)A

scala> case class Bip extends Foo with Bar

scala> val bip = Bip()
bip: Bip = Bip()

// looks good
scala> f(bip)
res0: Bip = Bip()

// only extends `Foo`
scala> case object Fip extends Foo
defined module Fip

// I expected a compile-time error
scala> f(Fip)
res1: Fip.type = Fip
```

How can I properly write `f` such that it only accepts an implementor of `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: Just to clarify one point, `def f[A <: Foo, Bar]...` doesn't mean what you think it means. It groups like `( A <: Foo ) , Bar`. In other words, you are creating another type variable named `Bar`, shadowing the trait `Bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use compound types to do this.

```
trait Foo
trait Bar
def f(a: Foo with Bar) = ???

scala> val foobar = new Foo with Bar
foobar: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@1b8c25c0

scala> f(foobar) // Happily accepts a class that mixes Foo and Bar
res26: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@1b8c25c0

scala> f(new Foo{})  // Refuses a class that only mixes Foo
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo(in object $iw)
 required: Foo(in object $iw) with Bar
```

The same syntax can be used with a type parameter, though I don't see it as necessary here.

```
def f[A <: Foo with Bar](a: A) = a

scala> f(foobar)  // Accepts a class that mixes Foo and Bar
res29: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@1b8c25c0

scala> f(new Foo{})  // Refuses a class with only Foo, as it breaks the type bounds
<console>:25: error: inferred type arguments [Foo] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: Foo with Bar]
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo
 required: A
```

Another way you could write it is:

```
def f[A](a: A with Foo with Bar) = ...
```

Comment: if `Foo` were a case class and `Bar` remained a trait, would `A <: Foo with Bar` be required?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Is `Foo` a class that mixes in `Bar`? If you want `A` to be both `Foo` and `Bar`, then `A <: Foo with Bar` is still required. They don't need to be traits. You could have `A <: Int with Bar`, for instance.

Comment: I don't see the type parameter as necessary though. The compound parameter works just fine.

Comment: ... Unless of course you want return/have more type information about `A`.